# reporting comparison statistic in barplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I need to place brackets for pairwise comparisons, along with the effect size and the p-value/significance in a barplot in which I am plotting the means of my data.

The package `ggpubr` offers a number of solutions, among which the command `geom_pwc`/`stat_pwc`: https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/geom_pwc.html. However, this command runs the stats on the actual data on the fly, so it may not be suitable for barplots plotting a summary dataset.

Does anyone have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: Provide some example data and an example of your desired output, and you will get tons of help :)